# Gridview header text unclickable when replaced in sorting

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview

My gridview sorting works fine by clicking the header and I don't replace the header text. But I need to replace the header text to show if the sorting is asc or desc after clicking like this:

"INSURED'S NAME" --> "INSURED'S NAME ▲"

```
   (Default)               (Sorted)
```

AllowSorting is set to true and here's the code from the code behind:

```
protected void gvMasterList_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            string sort_direct = ViewState["SortDirection"].ToString();
            DataTable dtMasterList = QueryVMSSummary();
            dtMasterList.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + sort_direct;
            gvMasterList.DataSource = dtMasterList;
            gvMasterList.DataBind();

            string _sort_image = SortImage();

            SetSortDirection(ViewState["SortDirection"].ToString());

            int columnIndex = 0;
            foreach (DataControlFieldHeaderCell headerCell in gvMasterList.HeaderRow.Cells )
            {
                if (headerCell.ContainingField.SortExpression == e.SortExpression)
                {
                    columnIndex = gvMasterList.HeaderRow.Cells.GetCellIndex(headerCell);
                }
            }

            gvMasterList.HeaderRow.Cells[columnIndex].Text = gvMasterList.Columns[columnIndex].HeaderText + " " + _sort_image;
        }
```

if I don't change the header text after clicking, it's ok, the sorting works fine, but if I changed the header text after clicking to add an Up and down arrow, the header text becomes unclickable. I've also tried putting the renaming of headertext inside the OnDataBound, but still won't work

Any idea so solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Add image to the header column as an independent control instead of adding it as a part of text. Here is an example that implements filtering but it also has sorting which satisfy your requirements. http://technobird.blogspot.com.au/2015/05/aspnet-gridview-with-filter-in-header.html

Comment: Yeah, I guess changing the text wouldn't do. Thanks.